# What is $\overline{D(f)}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring, $f\in A$. If $A$ is Noetherian, $\text{Spec}(A)$ has finitely many irreducible components, let us call them $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^n$. So we write

$$D(f)=\bigcup_{i=1}^n D(f)\cap Z_i. $$

Taking closures on both sides we get that $\overline{D(f)}$ is the union of the $Z_i$ meeting $D(f)$, since non-empty open subsets of $Z_i$ are dense in it.

I want to consider the general case, when $A$ is not necessarily Noetherian.
$$\overline{D(f)}=\bigcup_{i\in I} \overline{D(f)}\cap Z_i,$$
if $D(f)\cap Z_i$ is non-empty, $\overline{D(f)}\cap Z_i=Z_i$. We would conclude if we prove
$$ D(f)\cap Z_i = \emptyset \Rightarrow \overline{D(f)}\cap Z_i= \emptyset.$$ Is this last fact true?

Another approach could be considering that

$$\overline{D(f)}=\{\mathfrak{p}\in \text{Spec}(A):\bigcap_{f\notin \mathfrak{q}}\mathfrak{q}\subset \mathfrak{p}\}.$$

Now $\bigcap_{f\notin \mathfrak{q}}\mathfrak{q}=\bigcap_{f\notin \mathfrak{a}}\mathfrak{a}$, where the $\mathfrak{a}$ are minimal prime ideals. Is it true that $\bigcap_{f\notin \mathfrak{a}}\mathfrak{a}\subset \mathfrak{p}$ implies $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{p}$ for some $\mathfrak{a}$?

Comment: For the question whether $D(f)\cap Z_i = \emptyset$ implies that $\overline{D(f)}\cap Z_i = \emptyset$, consider $A=k[x,y]/(xy)$, $k$ an algebraically closed field. $D(x)$ is the punctured $x$-axis, which does not meet the $y$-axis; but its closure does.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should have thought about this before.